# ImportError: No module name xxx - How not to permanently set System variables

Tags: python, batch-file

I'm running `python 3.4.2` under Windows 7. I have some modules that I do NOT want to put (at least yet) into the python subdirectories. After much angst, I've gotten them to run, but only at the expense of adding `PYTHONHOME` and `PYTHONPATH` to my System variables.

I tried creating a batch file, set these and then executed my script. I tried setx, but this just puts the variables in my User variables where python does not appear to recognize them.

I find it hard to believe that I can't distribute some of these scripts to my co-workers without forcing them to change their System variables.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: That's the whole point of a package.

Comment: Can you show a sample directory structure and file snippets that reproduces your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you understand the module search path. https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path

Beyond that, one option is to prepend any directories where you have dependencies to sys.path before your import statements.

Answer (score 0):

As has been pointed out elsewhere setting pythonpath and pythonhome were probably not the best of ideas, especially in my newbie case because they ended up interferring with gcloud. I ended up adjusting my scripts so they sys.path.append("ZXYLIB") where XYXLIB is a path I set the the batch file calls the python, and that works.